# HTML Table different number of columns in different rows

Tags: html

Like in Excel sheet can I have

1. 2 columns in 1st row
2. 1 long column in the 2nd row

is this possible in html ?

Comment: is this the way <td colspan="2"> ?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

On the realisation that you're unfamiliar with `colspan`, I presumed you're also unfamiliar with `rowspan`, so I thought I'd throw that in for free.

One important point to note, when using `rowspan`: the following `tr` elements *must* contain fewer `td` elements, because of the cells using `rowspan` in the previous row (or previous *rows*).

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Column one and two</th>
      <th>Column three</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" colspan="2">A large cell</td>
      <td>a smaller cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- note that this row only has _one_ td, since the preceding row
                     takes up some of this row -->
      <td>Another small cell</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Found this demo which is quite informative: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_span

Answer (score 27):

Colspan:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td> Row 1 Col 1</td>
      <td> Row 1 Col 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
      <td colspan=2> Row 2 Long Col</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 8):

yes, simply use [colspan](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp).

Answer (score 3):

If you need different column width, do this:

```
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="9">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```