# How to make a <td> on more than one row?

Tags: html, css

How I can make a TD one more than one row in HTML?

To make it like this:

http://quebecencalvaire.ca/sov/this.png

The avatar is a TD and the sidebar another, but they are both in the same table of the TD "some text"...

It's for a profile page...

Comment: *Possible* duplicate of [HTMl Table different number of columns in different rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838488/html-table-different-number-of-columns-in-different-rows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check out the `rowspan` and `colspan` attributes.

As explained [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.6).

Comment: Please consider linking to resources that are more reliable, such as W3C itself or the Mozilla Developer Network. See http://w3fools.com/

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `rowspan`

You can read more here: http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/th/rowspan

As an example:

`<td rowspan="2">Whatever</td>`

Answer (score 0):

The link below will shows you the code for your problem...
http://jsfiddle.net/tashniamit/SCwWt/