# inserting table with rows and columns in the message body of email in ios

Tags: ios

I have created email using MFMailComposeViewController method. I need to insert a table with rows and columns in the message body of email.So please help.

Answer (score 2):

You can set html as the content body and use some html code to draw a table inside that.

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
NSString *emailBody = @"<html>....</html>"; //html code for drawing table
[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];
```

To draw a table in html use something like,

```
<table border=1>
 <thead><tr><td>#</td><td>Name</td></tr></thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>One</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td><td>Two</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td><td>Three</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td><td>Four</td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

For more details on how to draw table using html code, you can check some stackoverflow questions such as [HTML Table different number of columns in different rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838488/html-table-different-number-of-columns-in-different-rows)

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. I could create the table. But not able to pass the value to table.                                         NSString *e=self.phone;
 NSString *f=self.cost;                                     NSString *emailBody=@"<html>....</html>";                          I need to pass the value "e" as mentioned above and "f" to the table in html.How to do it? Can you please reply to it.

Comment: @user1871697, You can use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<thead><tr><td>#</td><td>%@</td></tr></thead>", nameParam]` to append the strings. You need to join the above code with required values using this. You can use multiple `stringWithFormat` and then join all the strings using this. `%@` is the format to insert a string between another string as shown above.