# How to set the cell column and cell width in html tables?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTMl Table different number of columns in different rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838488/html-table-different-number-of-columns-in-different-rows)

How to design the below one using html tables

```
    ----------------------------------
    |                  |             |
    |                  |             |
    |                  |             |
    |--------------------------------|                                
    |      |                         |
    |      |                         |
    |      |                         |
     ---------------------------------
```

Comment: Don't use tables for design. People here at SO will tell you that tables are used for displaying tabular data and you should use divs for your design.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938099/html-table-cell-width-for-different-rows

Comment: [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend using tables for creating that kind of layout, but if you really must use HTML tables, `colspan` attribute is the answer to your problem.

See the link and try the examples: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp