# Non-Standard Free Width Height HTML Table

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to get an HTML markup that represents the following table layout:

[image]

I tried this but it's not working:

```
       <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td style="height: 800px">
                    1
                </td>
                <td style="width: 300px; height: 400px">
                    2
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="height: 200px">
                    <p>3</p>
                </td>
                <td style="height: 600px">
                    4
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML Table different number of columns in different rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838488/html-table-different-number-of-columns-in-different-rows)

Comment: Doesn't work because I still need 4 cells

Comment: I wouldn't use a table to do this, I suggest using some div's.

Comment: Since that will most likely not represent tabular data, you should not use a table in the first place.,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks pretty close to the image you provided. It's a little tricky because it actually requires 3 rows, but once you get your head wrapped around `rowspan`, then it makes sense.

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr style="height: 200px;">
    <td style="width: 400px;" rowspan="2">
      1
    </td>
    <td style="width: 200px;">
      2
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height: 200px;">
    <td rowspan="2">
      4
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height: 50px;">
    <td>
      <p>3</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Darn IE. :-) If you move the height styles to the `tr`s, then it works with IE 11. I've updated this answer to do that instead. However, I think that mikelt21's alternate approach with floating divs is superior, as long as you don't _need_ to use tables for whatever reason

Comment: Thank you,
And as a last fiddle (dynamic width for the first column): http://jsfiddle.net/fb6fL5vL/

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add another row and add rowspans:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 300px; height: 400px" rowspan="2">
            1
        </td>
        <td style="width: 300px; height: 200px">
            2
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="height: 200px" rowspan="2">
            4
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="height: 100px">
            3
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**See jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mt009cha/**

**EDIT**

Do you have to use tables? This seems more like a layout and divs might be more appropriate.

Html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        <div style="height: 498px">1</div>
        <div style="height: 98px">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div style="height: 298px">2</div>
        <div style="height: 298px">4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.container {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
}

.left {
    width: 398px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.right {
    width: 198px;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
}
```

**See jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zynt5j7e/**

Comment: Sorry, I had to uncheck the answer because it doesn't work with IE.

Comment: if you don't need to use tables try my updated solution. i verified that it works in IE.

Answer (score 1):

[FIDDL](http://jsfiddle.net/vnc8ww89/)

If you must use tables:

```
<table class="tbl">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td style="height: 800px">
                        <p>top left</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="height: 200px">
                        <p>bottom left</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td style="height: 400px">
                        <p>top left</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="height: 600px">
                        <p>bottom left</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Some CSS:

```
.tbl, .tbl table { border-collapse: collapse; width:100%; }
.tbl td, .tbl table td{ border:1px solid black; padding:0; margin: 0; }
```

Comment: I ended up using your approach because it's more maintainable. Thanks,

Comment: @yazanpro If this helped you please click the checkmark by my answer to select it :)