# how to implement in ExtJs different number of columns in different rows

Tags: extjs, grid

is it possible to [do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838488/html-table-different-number-of-columns-in-different-rows) in extjs grid?
I couldn't find how to do it...

My Grid suppose to have

row of 5 columns

row of single column

row of 5 columns

row of single column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in Ext because columns are defined for the whole grid, not individually for rows.

Nevertheless, aren't you looking for this: http://dev.sencha.com/ext/5.1.0/examples/kitchensink/#row-expander-grid?

I think you can start with all rows expanded.

Comment: No, row expander has been around for some time, I think since version 2 so it's included in 4.2 for sure