# How do I add a caption to tables in a doxygen markdown file?

Tags: doxygen

I would like to know how to add a caption to a table defined in a markdown file for Doxygen. I know that Doxygen can generate a table from the following code in a .md file, but I could not find a way to add a caption to this table.

```
|Name |Age|
|-----|---|
|Alice| 18|
|Bob  | 23|
```

Answer (score 2):

do you mean something like this, which is possible

```
###H6

|Header1 | Header2 | Header 3 |
|--------|---------|----------|
|0       | 1       | 7        |
|2       | 5       | 3        |
|9       | 7       | 2        |
```

or something like this, which is not possible, at least not by only using simple .md notation

```
|          Caption            |
|Header1 | Header2 | Header 3 |
|--------|---------|----------|
|0       | 1       | 7        |
|2       | 5       | 3        |
|9       | 7       | 2        |
```

if you want the second version you should use [.html tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838488/html-table-different-number-of-columns-in-different-rows)

Unfortunately the second is impossible in doxygen.

1. you would need [multimarkdown](http://etherealmind.com/who-am-i/markdown-reference/) support, which is shown by the link the table example but is not supported by [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/markdown.html#markdown_extra) yet, right now doxygen only supports simple tables
2. you use only html
3. you find a workaround which suites you, something like this:

   ```
   <table>
   <tr>
   <td colspan=1>
        Caption
   </td>
   |Header1 | Header2 | Header 3 |
   |--------|---------|----------|
   |0       | 1       | 7        |
   |2       | 5       | 3        |
   |9       | 7       | 2        |
   </tr>
   ```

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for a way to do the second case.

Comment: @AkiraOkumura yes you could also do a mix like version 3.